# grpc request without any request param

Tags: grpc, grpc-python

I have a grpc server with request of type:

```
service AbcService {
 rpc GetInfo(GetInfoRequest) returns (GetInfoResponse) {}
}

message GetInfoRequest {}
message GetInfoResponse {
  string hostname = 3;
}
```

And this is my client:

```
channel = grpc.insecure_channel('test.url:1025')
client = svc_pb2_grpc.AbcServiceStub(channel)

# get response
resp = client.GetInfo
```

I am facing issues with the client, since I am not able to get any response from it. `grpcurl` works simply fine using:
`grpcurl -plaintext test.url:1025 AbcService/GetInfo`

Is `resp = client.GetInfo` the right way in client to invoke this call (which is not expecting any request parameter)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "stub" encapsulates your server with a class, where the different API calls (requests/responses) are method calls.

So first of all:
`resp = client.GetInfo()`

However, `GetInfo` expects an `GetInfoRequest`, so you need:

`resp = client.GetInfo(GetInfoRequest())`